# SCDF support for multiple java versioned spring boot application streams

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

If I have spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local:1.5.2.RELEASE deployed, would custom apps built with later version of Java beyond 8 BE supported or scdf would have to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Apps have no dependency with respect to the orchestration mechanics in SCDF.

The later versions of Java are supported in Spring Boot 2.0 and over, so as far as your Apps are on this baseline, SCDF should be able to deploy them to the target platforms.

The out-of-the-box [2.0 Apps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Darwin.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/) (aka Darwin release-train) have been upgraded to this Boot 2.x baseline for the same reason. You can have a mix of 1.x and 2.x Apps in a data pipeline in SCDF - interoperability is supported as well.